# Label a Grid with the arguments of a function

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts

I would like to make a table with row and column headings being the arguments to a function and the values to be the value of the function. So far, I have this:

```
cosine[r_, theta_] := Sqrt[2 r^2 (1 - Cos[theta/360 * 2*Pi])];

m = Table[cosine[r, theta], {r, 1000, 10000, 1000}, {theta, .5, 2, .5}]

Grid[m]
```

This prints out the values. How do I get the r-values to be along the side and the theta values as the column headings, ideally with lines to make it clear they are headings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2:** Rather than processing the table `m` to add headers, we can define a function `modifyF` that modifies `f` to return first and/or second argument passed to `f` for specific argument patterns; and, then use `modifyF[f]` to construct the table. One way, out of many ways, to do that is:

```
ClearAll[modifyF];
modifyF[f_] := {##} /. {{_String, a_} :> a, {b_, _String} :> b, 
                        {_String, _String} :> "", {x_, y_} :> f[x, y]} &;
```

Examples:

```
Table[modifyF[cosine][r, t], 
     {r, Prepend[1000 Range[10], ""]}, {t, Prepend[.5 Range[4], ""]}] // Grid
```

[image]

To get the first argument as the row header, prepend the iterator list for the column index  with a `String` element`:

```
Table[modifyF[cosine][r, t], {r, 1000 Range[10]}}, {t, Prepend[.5 Range[4], ""]}] // Grid
```

[image]

Similarly, To get the second argument as the colum header, prepend the iterator list for the row index with a `String` element`:

```
Table[modifyF[cosine][r, t], {r,  Prepend[1000 Range[10], ""]}, {t, .5 Range[4]}] // Grid
```

[image]

**Update:** Define a function that takes a matrix and row and column headers:

```
headersF = Module[{jtF=Join@@{{#2}, Transpose@#}&}, Fold[jtF, #, {#2, Join@@{{""}, #3}}]]&;
headersF[m, 1000 Range[10], .5 Range[4]] // Grid
```

[image]

The following two variations give the same output as `headerF`:

```
headersF2 = Module[{ptF=Prepend[Transpose@#, #2]&}, Fold[ptF, #, {#2, Join@@{{""}, #3}}]]&;
headersF3 = Fold[Transpose[ArrayFlatten[{{#2, #}}]] &, #, 
                 List /@ # & /@ {#2, ArrayPad[#3, {1, 0}, ""]}] &;
```

---

```
rows = Range[1000, 10000, 1000];
cols = Prepend[Range[.5, 2, .5], ""];
```

The following all give the same output as above:

```
Prepend[Transpose[Prepend[Transpose@m, rows]], cols] // Grid
ptF = Prepend[Transpose@#, #2] &;  Fold[ptF, m, {rows, cols}] // Grid
tF = Join @@ {{#2}, Transpose@#} &; Fold[jtF, m, {rows, cols}] // Grid
ArrayPad[ArrayPad[m, {{0}, {1, 0}}, List /@ rows], {{1, 0}, {0}}, cols]  // Grid
```

Alternatively, you can use `TableForm`:

```
TableForm[m, TableHeadings -> {rows, Rest@cols}]
```

Comment: The prepend form certainly is tortuous. I was hoping for a way to do it without going to the length of creating row/col arrays, but I guess that is inevitable.

Comment: @Tyler, updated with hopefully less "torturous" alternatives:) I think a single application of `ArrayPad` should do the job but I could not find right form yet.