# Center column heading in TableForm

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, numerical-value, alignment

I have a TableForm as follows:

```
cosine[r_, theta_] := Sqrt[2 r^2 (1 - Cos[theta/360 * 2*Pi])];
rows = Range[1000, 10000, 1000];
cols = Prepend[Range[.5, 2, .5], ""];
TableForm[m, TableHeadings -> {rows, Rest@cols}, TableAlignments -> "."]
```

which produces:

[image: Mathematica Table]

However, I would like to center the column headings and remove all the trailing decimal points. I have not found any way to center just the column headings while keeping the values decimal/right aligned. I have seen some complicated methods of removing the decimal point by converting the values to a string and then doing string manipulations to remove the decimal point, which seems like a hack to me, so I am hoping there is a straightforward way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
cosine[r_, theta_] := Sqrt[2 r^2 (1 - Cos[theta/360*2*Pi])];
m = Table[IntegerPart[cosine[r, t]], {r, 1000, 10000, 1000}, {t, 0.5, 2., .5}];
rows = Range[1000, 10000, 1000];
TableForm[m, TableHeadings -> {rows, {"0.5", "1.0", "1.5", "2.0"}}, TableAlignments -> Right]
```

[image]

Note that `m` is undefined in your question, but I surmise that my definition is close to what you intended.

Answer (score 4):

Of OP's two requirements

1. center the column headings and
2. remove all the trailing decimal points.

@bbgodfrey's answer addresses the second.

Unfortunately, getting both requirements, i.e.,

> to center just the column headings while keeping the values decimal/right aligned.

using `TableForm` is impossible since `TableAlignments` is not flexible enough to align individual rows, columns or items separately. That is, aligments can only be specified for each dimension (rows and/or columns), and row (column) headers inherit the alignment settings of the rows (columns). This can be seen by modifying the input matrix `m` in bbgodfrey's answer:

```
m = Table[IntegerPart[cosine[r, t]], {r, 1000, 10000, 1000}, {t, 0.5, 2., .5}];
mb = RandomChoice[{1, 100, 10000}] # & /@ m;
rows = 1000 Range[10]; cols = .5 Range[4];
Column[Table[Labeled[Grid[{Table[TableForm[i, TableHeadings -> {rows, cols}, 
       TableAlignments -> j], {i, {m, mb}}]}, ItemSize -> All, Dividers -> All], 
        Style[TableAlignments -> j, 16], Top], {j, {Right, Center}}], Spacer[15], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

A work-around is to wrap column headings with `Pane` or `Framed`:

```
TableForm[mb, TableHeadings -> {rows, 
     Pane[#, ImageSize -> {Scaled[.1], Automatic}, Alignment -> Center] & /@ cols}, 
  TableAlignments -> Right]
```

[image]

**Using `Grid`:**

A much more flexible approach is to use `Grid. To use`Grid`we need to add row and column headers to the input matrix`mb`. This can be done in a number of ways using any of the methods suggested [in this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/74017/125) answer to the OP's related question. For example,

```
hF = Fold[Prepend[Transpose@#, #2] &, #, {#2, Join @@ {{""}, #3}}] &;

mb2 = hF[mb, rows, cols];
```

Now, we can use `Item` with the option `Alignment->Center` to modify the the first row of `mb2`

```
mb3 = mb2; 
mb3[[1]] = Item[#, Alignment -> Center] & /@ mb3[[1]];
Grid[mb3, Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}, Alignment -> Right]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use the third element of the `Alignment` option settings for `Grid` to set the alignments for the elements in the first row:

```
Grid[mb2, Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True},
 Alignment -> {Right, Center, MapIndexed[{1, 1 + First@#2} -> Center &, cols]},
 ItemStyle -> {{Directive[Red, 20, Italic, "Panel"]}, {Directive[Blue, 20, Italic, "Panel"]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: For times with wide numeric columns, such as you have illustrated, one alternative to centering per se, might be to convert the heading to a string with a few spaces at the right. This might position the headings roughly in the middle of the number with an average length, giving an aesthetic result, even though it is not a true centering of the column label.

Comment: @Tyler, you can also use `Pane` or `Frame` (both with the option `Alignment->Center`) to wrap each of the column headers and experiment with different values for `ImageSize`.