# TableForm: How can I center the heading labels while aligning numbers on the decimal?

Tags: alignment

In Mathematica 10.4 I'd like to center the column headings in my table while continuing to align the column entries on the decimal point. Here's an example:

```
data = {{3.`, 12.03504555`, 12.023009030063605`, 12.023376796911684`, 
         0.0010001225077536091`, 0.0009695645138888542`}, {11.`, 
         1.836680386`, 1.8363040407777864`, 1.8363031611946115`, 
         0.00020490512398463334`, 0.00020538402231751185`}}; 
TableForm[data, TableHeadings -> {None, {E - Subscript[E, F], "refVal", "myFastVal",
 "myAccurateVal", 1 - myFastVal/refVal, 1 - myAccurateVal/refVal}}, TableAlignments -> "."]
```

TableAlignments->"." causes the numeric rows to align on the decimal but the heading row remains left aligned, so the heading labels are offset relative to the data in their columns.  Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: The styling of your question can be improved. Please take the time to read the [**markdown help page**](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You'll better communicate your problem when you use the right formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TableAlignments` is not flexible enough to align individual rows, columns or items separately. That is, alignments can only be specified for each dimension (rows and/or columns), and row (column) headers inherit the alignment settings of the rows (columns). See also [this closely related q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74020/125).

`Grid` is more convenient to use to get what you need:

```
columnheaders = Item[#, Alignment -> Right] & /@ {E - Subscript[E, F], "refVal", 
    "myFastVal", "myAccurateVal", 1 - myFastVal/refVal, 1 - myAccurateVal/refVal};

Grid[Prepend[data, columnheaders], Dividers -> {None, 2 -> True}, Alignment -> "."]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works.

Comment: @JohnV., my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. Welcome to mma.se.